# 404 Page not found on page refresh

Tags: javascript, azure, routes, react-router, devops

I have a basic create-react-app configurations and it is deployed on Azure devops. My backend is also deployed on Azure Devops in python.

All the services and UI are deployed on Kubernetes cluster.

The website works fine on the BASE_URL, it points to index.html and loads the page on routing back to it or refresh it also.

I am able to move forward in the flow with the application.

**For ex:  BASE_URL --> BASE_URL/about** (works fine)

**BASE_URL/about**

- ( on refresh, it shows `404 | The requested path could not be found`)

I'm using  `{ BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom"`

From what I read and understood, the server does not understand it because URL is changed locally and client handles it, when we click a link, some Javascript runs which manipulates the URL in the address bar, without causing a page refresh, and in turn causes React Router to perform a page transition on the client-side.

**Things I tried:**

- Added ***web.config*** in /public folder (Issue not solved)

```js
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- **Added staticwebapp.config.json** in /public folder (Issue not solved) from [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#example-configuration-file)

```js
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html",
    "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
  }
}
```

- Added **`<base href="/">`** in  tag of /public/index.html before JS and CSS (Issue not solved, encountered in stackoverflow answers)

Can anyone guide what am I missing, or there needs to be any external configurations to be done in index.html or devops?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue - my routes.json file was in the root

I added the routes.json to the public folder and it worked.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
       "route": "/*",
       "serve": "/index.html",
       "statusCode": 200
    }
 ],
 "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": ["/images/*.{png,jpg,gif}", "/css/*"]
   }
}
```